# Creating an executable Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, exe, pyinstaller, seaborn

I just finished my first work with python and I would like to create an executable file to distribution. However, I am having trouble to do this. I already tried py2exe, pyinstaller and cx_freeze with no success. Searching for lots of opinions, I belive pyinstaller is the best solution for my problem, but I can make it work. The imports I do in my program are below:

```
import os
import pygtk
import gtk
import MySQLdb
import getpass as gt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.io import sql
from scipy import stats, integrate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
```

Reading the documentation of pyinstaller I notice that it only doesn't work with the libs scikitlearn (sklearn) and seaborn. When I use 'pyinstaller --onefile Principal.py' I get the build and dist pastes, but when I try to run the .exe file I get the following message:

```
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI82242\gtk\__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning:
 PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6fpfyh\pyinstaller\PyInstall
er\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 363, in load_module
  File "c:\users\lucas\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13,
in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: lib not built. If you want to import pandas from the s
ource directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to bu
ild the C extensions first.
Principal returned -1
```

Can someone help me with what I have to do?

Comment: Maybe you could look at using Docker? I don't think "packaging python to exe" is a very well-supported or recommended workflow

Comment: Your app need rebuild pandas package on create app. Importing module (pandas) isn't redistributable. Some package required compiling. Install ready for use library. You can't use inside a .exe if haven't source code. Is not an error, missing package (source)!

Comment: So what are you recommending I do? I'm trying to create an executable to later create an installer using Inno (he asks for an .exe file). If I use the exe that pyinstaller creates to me and add the paths of pandas and the others libs in Inno should my program work?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your python is not able to build a C based package (**numpy**). It might be that some of libraries where installed :

- within your python distribution (anaconda)
- using a wheel installation file (.whl) which precompiled the package

You can try to solve this problem in two ways:

- install the latest **[MS Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003)** compiler so you will use **vcvarsall.bat** for C extensions
- install the latest [**Visual Studio Community**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) which include an IDE and the compilers for a plenty of languages. This second option normally works but it requires more than 6 gb om your hard drive

After this installation you can launch what the error message was telling you:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```